# How to Redirect login.php to other url in X-cart

Tags: php, x-cart

Please check Below Both URL and help me:-

http://www.xyz.com/login.php to Redirect http://www.xyz.com/Phase-2

Please Help me.

Thanks

Comment: open google and type "php redirect"

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to do this. Here you have some examples.

**.htaccess solution**

```
 Redirect 301 /login.php   http://www.xyz.com/Phase-2
```

**Php solution**

```
// login.php

<?php
header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");
header("Location:  http://www.xyz.com/Phase-2 ");
exit();
?>
```

**HTML solution ( not a 301 redirect )**

```
<html>
<head>
   <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url= http://www.xyz.com/Phase-2 ">
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```